# Why Error MT5210: Linking fails for debug ARM64 Builds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm seeing errors in my logs like

```
MT5209 ignoring file libmono-native-unified.a file is universal (armv7,armv7s,arm64) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture Native linking
```

However I'm trying to build the project for iOS in debug mode, so it should be using arm64 as the architecture, so I'm not sure why it's trying to use x86_64 at all.  This implies it's building for a simulator instead of the selected device.

[image: Fails to run debug on physical iOS device]

Comment: Does the 'Debug|iPhone' option appear when you try to create a new project?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see my debug iPhone configuration is set to ARM64 (correct)

[image: Debug iPhone]

And only the simulator is set to x86

[image: Debug iPhone - simulator]

**SOLUTION -** If I swap the build configuration from 'Debug' to 'Debug|iPhone' it compiles just fine, e.g.

FROM

[image]

TO

[image]

So why 'Debug' and platform 'iPhone' doesn't work and 'Debug|iPhone' does I'm not sure.

Comment: Originally, Debug config was only used for Android. Sounds like a bug with VS Platform setting.